# unable to find remote helper for 'https' windows

Tags: python, windows, git, heroku, https

I am trying to push a local git repo to Heroku server using 'git push heroku master'. 
But I'm getting an error

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

I have my remote configured with name heroku.
I found many solution for linux to install curl-devel, but how do I do it on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, HTTPS with the Windows Git client works out of the box.

I once encountered this problem on Windows, and found out that my anti-virus blocked access. I could resolve the problem after configuring the anti-virus program control settings.

In case that doesn't help, consider reinstalling Git.